# Redirecting immediately with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a problem redirecting a page with JavaScript. I want to redirect the page after clicking a button, but it is redirecting it automatically.
Why is that?

```
window.onload=initAll; 
function initAll(){
   if(window.addEventListener) {
      document.getElementById('check').addEventListener("click",redirection,false);
   } else if (window.attachEvent){ 
      document.getElementById('check').attachEvent("onclick", redirection);
   }
   function redirection(){
      window.location.href='http://www.google.com';
   }
}

  
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="glavna.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="wrapper">
         <form action="glavna.html">City:<input id="city" type="text"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            Price: From:<input type="text" id="from"/>&nbsp; To:<input type="text" id="to"/>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;Refresh in min :<input type="text" id="refresh"/>
            <button id="check" >Search</button>
         </form>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

this can be done with `window.location.href` what it does

```
// similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "you want to redirect";
```

Answer (score 0):

`window.location` is location object. To redirect Use `window.location.href` instead

Comment: Thanks for the respond ,still dont work,I pubished the final html and javascript in my first post

Comment: What Browser You are Trying ?

Comment: Where are your putting the above Javascript ? in your `glavna.js`? or in a `<script>` block ? This code working perfectly and redirecting here.

Comment: I am puting it in glavna.js.I posted bougth files in my first posting.Thanks

Comment: If instead of redirecting I put alert in the function redirect everithing works fine.But If I put redirect it doesnt go anywhere

Comment: Can you just do a `<form onsubmit="return false">` and give a feedback ? However Its just an wild guess as I don't see a submit button.